# connect to other e2c instance running mysql

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I'm trying to set up a connection from one e2c (amazon) instance towards another e2c instance.

I've:

1. Adapted the security group as follows: MYSQL/Aurora TCP 3306 client-ip/32 (with client-ip the literal ip address of my client instance
2. bind-address is set to 0.0.0.0 in my.cnf (that already took me some effort to find out)
3. iptables isn't running (or is at least not holding back anything)
4. I've rebooted the server after changing the security group
5. see list below for content of my user database
6. mysqld is restarted
7. after each grant I did flush privileges (on the server)

This command *does* work:

```
root@server:~# mysql -u root -p
```

this *doesn't*:

```
ubuntu@client:~$ mysql -u root -p -h server-ip mysql (with the literal ip address)
```

with following exception:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'ec2-client-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
```

output of:

```
select Host, User from user;

+---------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| Host                                              | User             |
+---------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| %                                                 | name             |
| 127.0.0.1                                         | root             |
| client-ip.ec2.internal                            | root             |
| client-ip                                         | phpmyadmin       |
| client-ip                                         | root             |
| ::1                                               | root             |
| ec2-client-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com     | phpmyadmin       |
| ec2-client-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com     | root             |
| ip-172-30-0-191                                   | root             |
| localhost                                         | debian-sys-maint |
| localhost                                         | liftoff          |
| localhost                                         | phpmyadmin       |
| localhost                                         | root             |
+---------------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

Don't worry, this *isn't* production (at all) just some playing around...

I really don't know what I'm overlooking here, maybe it's just something stupid, I have no idea why this isn't working.

```
telnet server-ip 3306
```

gives me the gibberish you would expect from a mysql server;

any help is *greatly* appreciated...

both instances are ubuntu, one Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (with mysql server 5.6) the client is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with mysql client 5.7; I really hope this is not the problem...

Comment: As you can conenct to MySQL this is a MySQL permissions problem, not Amazon or Ubuntu. You don't need to restart if you change security group rules, but you need to stop and start to change the security group of an EC2 instance (not even sure you can to be honest).

Comment: Hey Tim, can you be more specific of what I need to start and stop? I rebooted the instance with sudo reboot and I restarted the mysql server...

Comment: I said you didn't need to restart anything. Your problem is MySQL permissions, which can be tricky. I have a bit of information that could be helpful here - it applies to MySQL generally, not just RDS https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-3-migrating-wordpress-sites-into-aws/#rds

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently if you use:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'52-211-52-226.ec2.internal' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

without the IDENTIFIED BY clause it doesn't set a password:

```
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| User             | Password                                  |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| root             | *52906BB5BDD20058CC5D0540DF250D4CC034166F |
| root             | *52906BB5BDD20058CC5D0540DF250D4CC034166F |
| root             | *52906BB5BDD20058CC5D0540DF250D4CC034166F |
| root             | *52906BB5BDD20058CC5D0540DF250D4CC034166F |
| debian-sys-maint | *962FC5E27FD78F93284B9F0A4CE344B9748CEEFD |
| phpmyadmin       | *52906BB5BDD20058CC5D0540DF250D4CC034166F |
| liftoff          | *27EF2C2B8282406BA7B56DC96E8BE27C9988FBBB |
| phpmyadmin       |                                           |
| root             |                                           |
| phpmyadmin       |                                           |
| root             |                                           |
| name             | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
| root             |                                           |
| root             |                                           |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

...

```
mysql -u root -h 52.209.36.229 -p
```

didn't work but

```
mysql -u root -h 52.209.36.229
```

did...

sorry to have wasted your time :-/

S.

Comment: np - take care !

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to flush privilges

```
mysql> flush privileges;
```

That is to say *without* knowing to what database you granted privileges.
In the command you wrote you connect default to mysql database.

Usually you do

```
mysql> grant all privileges on my_db.* to 'user'@'host' deintified by 'secret';
mysql> /* for older versions */ flush privileges
shell$ mysql -u user -p -h mysql_host my_db
```

Comment: Hey silviud, I did that, it didn't work.

Comment: The original question says he did that already.

Comment: can you do this show ` show grants for 'root'@'ec2-client-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' `

Comment: also if you say you have done all this   ... do this too - mysql> select PASSWORD("password_for_root"); and than compare with the password you see into mysql.user for that user and host. ... I would un minus my answer since I do this by a while and works every time ;)